# htaccess 3rd parameter not working

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have an existing rule in my .htaccess that says

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([0-9]+)$ member.php?do=$1&uid=$2&id=$3 [L]
```

When I access a URL like `http://mysite/posts/3`, the second parameter is working perfectly..  The ugly url of it is this:

```
http://mysite/member.php?do=posts&uid=3
```

But when I tried adding a third parameter like this one:

```
http://mysite/posts/3/2
```

Ugly Url is

```
http://mysite/member.php?do=posts&uid=3&id=2
```

It is not working anymore... I got ERROR 404 Object not found.

What am I doing incorrectly?

Comment: This: `([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([0-9]+)` only has two capture groups, so `$3` can't ever exist

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rewrite rule

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([0-9]+)$ member.php?do=$1&uid=$2&id=$3 [L]
```

is wrong. It only catches "posts/3" but never "posts/3/2".

You can try adding 2 rules for example

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([0-9]+)$ member.php?do=$1&uid=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)$ member.php?do=$1&uid=$2&id=$3 [L]
```